# Display the PID with bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash

Good day all,

I am trying to write a bash script to show all processes of java, however i would like it to display in the below manner.

```
 ps -p $PID -o pid,vsz=MEMORY -o user,group=GROUP -o comm,args=ARGS
```

The problem with the above is that it only show one particular PID.

So I want to `ps aux|grep j\[a\]va` get the PID of each and then run each PID in the above command.

RESULT:

```
 root@reinhardt-VirtualBox:/home/reinhardt# ps -p 1959 -o pid,vsz=MEMORY -o user,group=GROUP -o comm,args=ARGS
  PID MEMORY USER     GROUP    COMMAND         ARGS
 1959  13648 root     root     grep            grep --color=auto java
```

I would guess some sort of loop will be made like for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in a place where I can test this, but this should work.  `read` is a standard part of shell scripting, it places something from stdin (which can be a stream, or a device such as /dev/tty) into a variable.  Then you just do a while loop

```
ps auwwx | gawk '/[j]ava/{print $1}' | while read PID
do
    ps -p $PID -o pid,vsz=MEMORY -o user,group=GROUP -o comm,args=ARGS
done
```

Or more simply, if your UNIX has pgrep:

```
pgrep java | while read PID
do
    ps -p $PID -o pid,vsz=MEMORY -o user,group=GROUP -o comm,args=ARGS
done
```

Sometimes you can use `xargs` in cases like these.  Remember that by default, xargs puts a group of arguments at the end of the command. So you need to feed it one at a time (with -n1) and place the PID where you want, with -i:

```
pgrep java | xargs -n1 -i{} ps -p {} -o pid,vsz=MEMORY -o user,group=GROUP -o comm,args=ARGS
```

(again, apologies if I get the -i syntax wrong, I can't test now.  Check manpage if this blows up)

Comment: Awesome, tried the 1st piece of code, 2 problems, it said gawk is not known. I then took out the g and then the script ran through the loop, however i am not sure if the PID is inserted into the $PID. I get "error: process ID list syntax error"

Comment: Oh and the last one is working perfectly!

Comment: @ReinhardtRatkasvanRooyen is this on a Mac?  My assumption was Linux, therefore gawk.

Comment: This is linux, Ubuntu 13